# C++ Template Inheritance. Subclass should replace a type in a base class with a fixed type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

how can I use a template base class in such a manner that the subclass make a template type "fix".

For example I have a template base class:

```
template <class A, int size> class BaseClass{
    private:
        A *elem;
    public:
        A()
        {
            elem = new A[size];
        }
};
```

I can do

```
BaseClass<int, 5> mybase;
```

Now I want to make a subclass which has only the parameter `size` and the type should be `int`, i.e. the subclass should replace type `A` in the base class with a  fixed type (e.g. `int`)

Something like this:

```
SubClass<5> mysubclass; 
// type should be fixed to int, e.g. mysubclass can do the same like mybase
```

Regards

Comment: Is there something preventing you from doing so?

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
template <int size>
using SubClass = BaseClass<int,size>;
```

It is not a subclass but, as far as I understand, does what you need. 
True subclass would be

```
template <int size>
class SubClass: public BaseClass<int,size> {
   ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define the derived class as

```
template <int size> 
class SubClass : public BaseClass<int, size> {
    ...
};
```

Then for `SubClass<5>`, the base class specialization would be `BaseClass<int, 5>`.